# Existence of Harder-Narasimhan filtration

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, vector-bundles

I am trying to understand the proof of the existence of Harder-Narasimhan filtration from Huybrechts and Lehn.

Let $X$ be a projective scheme with a fixed ample line bundle. Then the theorem says that every pure sheaf  has a unique Harder-Narasimhan filtration.

The book first proves the following lemma : let $E$ be a purely $d$-dimensional sheaf. Then there is a subsheaf $F\subset E$ such that for all subsheaves $G\subset E$ one has $p(F)\geq p(G) $ and in case of equality $G\subset F$. Moreover $F$ is uniquely determined and semistable. $F$ is the maximal destabilizing subsheaf.

My doubt is as follows. Once we establish the existence of such an $F$, the book says by induction we can assume that $E/F$ has a Harder Narasimhan filtration.

What are we inducting on? My guess is the dimension of the sheaf $E$. But if so I am not able to see why dimension of $E/F$ is strictly less than dimension of $ E$. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I remember this proof being terrible. I do think that one is inducting on dimension, since one then passes from $E$ to $E/\mathrm{HN}_1(E)$ which has strictly smaller dimension, and then proceeds from there.

Comment: Thanks @Alex! But can you tell me why it has strictly smaller dimension?

Answer (score 1):

I think we can induct on the rank of $E$. Look at the sequence $0 \to F \to E \to E/F \to 0$. Since $rk(E) = rk(F) + rk(E/F)$, and $F$ is a proper nonzero subsheaf of $E$, so $rk(E/F) < rk(E)$, and so we can proceed via induction.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking about induction on $\alpha_d(E)$, where $\alpha_d(E)/d!$ is the leading coefficient of the Hilbert polynomial of $E$, with the same notation as Huybrechts & Lehn. It is additive on exact sequences so we should have $\alpha_d(E/F)<\alpha_d(E)$. Moreover the base case $\alpha_d(E)=0$ should be trivial since it implies $E=0$ (by a previous remark after the definition of the Hilbert polynomial).

In fact thinking again about it, it is quite the same as inducting on the rank, since $\text{rk}(E)=\alpha_d(E)/\alpha_d(O_X)$; the only (apparent) problem with rank is that it is not an integer in general.